# CodeIgniter on EC2 showing index as blank page. How to fix?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I am new AWS.
I've created an EC2 Amazon Linux instance.
I am using CodeDeploy to deploy directly from GitHub.

So far this has been successful. I have installed httpd php56 on the EC2 Linux instance.
Code succesfully deployed from git.

The PHP framework I am using is CodeIgniter 2.

On the local machine, I am able to run the application fine.

On EC2 the index.php in root is showing up as blank... I assume either htaccess is failing or some other config is incorrect.

I've added info.php in the root folder and was able to execute that without any issue. SO its not a PHP issue.

here is the httpd.conf

```
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On localhost, i noticed the /assets/ return 403 which is what i want. 
In EC2 however /assets/ return the directory listing which is NOT what I want.

Hopefully that gives an idea on what may be the issue.

Not sure what else to look at.

Thanks in advance,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

Bro I think this may work because i had the same issue but mine was Ec2 instance ubuntu i installed lamp stack and other websites are working but the codeigniter was not working as they were showing a blank page the solution i found is that
first u need to check is the intl.so file exists in the extension directory if yes then u need to update the composer in the root directory of the project it will solve the issue

run this command to check if the intl.so file exists

```
php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');"
```

or check in the phpinfo()

the full details are in this link
https://www.dotkernel.com/php-troubleshooting/where-is-the-intl-php-extension-problem-solved/

after installing the intl.so file cd to your project root directory and
run the command
composer update

it will solve the issue